# Independent clause boundary disambiguation, and independent clause segmentation – any tools to do this?

Tags: nlp, text-segmentation

I remember skimming the sentence segmentation section from the NLTK site a long time ago.

I use a crude text replacement of “period” “space” with “period” “manual line break” to achieve sentence segmentation, such as with a Microsoft Word replacement (`.` -> `.^p`) or a Chrome extension:

https://github.com/AhmadHassanAwan/Sentence-Segmentation

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sentence-segmenter/jfbhkblbhhigbgdnijncccdndhbflcha

This is instead of an NLP method like the Punkt tokenizer of NLTK.

I segment to help me more easily locate and reread sentences, which can sometimes help with reading comprehension.

What about independent clause boundary disambiguation, and independent clause segmentation? Are there any tools that attempt to do this?

Below is some example text. If an independent clause can be identified within a sentence, there’s a split. Starting from the end of a sentence, it moves left, and greedily splits:

E.g.

> **Sentence** boundary disambiguation
>   (SBD), also known as sentence
>   breaking, is the problem in natural
>   language processing of deciding where
>
> sentences begin and end.
>
> **Often**, natural language processing
>   tools
>
> require their input to be divided into
>   sentences for a number of reasons.
>
> **However**, sentence boundary
>   identification is challenging because punctuation
>
> marks are often ambiguous.
>
> **For** example, a period may
>
> denote an abbreviation, decimal point,
>   an ellipsis, or an email address - not
>   the end of a sentence.
>
> **About** 47% of the periods in the Wall
>   Street Journal corpus
>
> denote abbreviations.[1]
>
> **As** well, question marks and
>   exclamation marks may
>
> appear in embedded quotations,
>   emoticons, computer code, and slang.
>
> **Another** approach is to automatically
>
> learn a set of rules from a set of
>   documents where the sentence
>
> breaks are pre-marked.
>
> **Languages** like Japanese and Chinese
>
> have unambiguous sentence-ending
>   markers.
>
> **The** standard 'vanilla' approach to
>
> locate the end of a sentence:
>
> (a) **If**
>
> it's a period,
>
> it ends a sentence.
>
> (b) **If** the preceding
>
> token is on my hand-compiled list of
>   abbreviations, then
>
> it doesn't end a sentence.
>
> (c) **If** the next
>
> token is capitalized, then
>
> it ends a sentence.
>
> **This**
>
> strategy gets about 95% of sentences
>   correct.[2]
>
> **Solutions** have been based on a maximum
>   entropy model.[3]
>
> **The** SATZ architecture uses a neural
>   network to
>
> disambiguate sentence boundaries and
>   achieves 98.5% accuracy.

(I’m not sure if I split it properly.)

If there are no means to segment independent clauses, are there any search terms that I can use to further explore this topic?

Thanks.

Comment: In the examples in your question, you seem to be splitting at independent clauses as well as dependent clauses. Some splits are not clauses at all. (e.g. "disambiguate sentence ... accuracy" is a conjunction of 2 clauses). Very interesting question for computational linguists, though. Upvote for that.

Comment: I’m looking at it like, once an independent clause is found (e.g. disambiguate sentence boundaries) within the sentence, just split at the left of where it starts. There is no concern for what the parts are after the split.

If it became “disambiguate sentence boundaries, and it achieves 98.5% accuracy.” (2 inner independent clauses). I would split it at the left of “it” for “it achieves”, and the left of “disambiguate” for “disambiguate boundaries”.

But you’re right; “disambiguate … accuracy” as a whole isn’t an independent clause, and it doesn’t make sense on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no readily available tool to solve this exact problem. Usually, NLP systems do not get into the problem of identifying different types of sentences and clauses as defined by English grammar. There is one paper published in EMNLP which provides an algorithm which uses the `SBAR` tag in parse trees to identify *independent* and *dependent* clauses in a sentence.

You should find [section 3 of this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2391122) useful. It talks about English language syntax in some details, but I don't think the entire paper is relevant to your question.

Note that they have used the Berkeley parser ([demo available here](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html)), but you can obviously any other constituency parsing tool (e.g. the Stanford parser [demo available here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)).

Answer (score 1):

Chthonic Project gives some good information here:

[Clause Extraction using Stanford parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070245/clause-extraction-using-stanford-parser)

Part of the answer:

> It is probably better if you primarily use the constituenty-based
> parse tree, and not the dependencies.
>
> The clauses are indicated by the **SBAR** tag, which is a *clause
> introduced by a (possibly empty) subordinating conjunction*.
>
> All you need to do is the following:
>
> 1. Identify the non-root clausal nodes in the parse tree
> 2. Remove (but retain separately) the subtrees rooted at these clausal nodes from the main tree.
> 3. In the main tree (after removal of subtrees in step 2), remove any *hanging* prepositions, subordinating conjunctions and adverbs.
>
> For a list of all clausal tags (and, in fact, all Penn Treebank tags),
> see this list:
> http://www.surdeanu.info/mihai/teaching/ista555-fall13/readings/PennTreebankConstituents.html
>
> For an online parse-tree visualization, you may want to use the
> [online Berkeley parser demo](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html).
>
> It helps a lot in forming a better intuition.
>
> Here's the image generated for your example sentence:
> [image: Berkeley Parser Tree]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any tools that do clause segmentation, but in rhetorical structure theory, there is a concept called "elementary discourse unit" which work in a similar way as a clause. They are sometimes, however, slightly smaller than clauses.

You may see the section 2.0 of this manual for more information about this concept:

https://www.isi.edu/~marcu/discourse/tagging-ref-manual.pdf

There are some software available online that can segment sentence into their elementary discourse unit , for instance:

http://alt.qcri.org/tools/discourse-parser/

and

https://github.com/jiyfeng/DPLP

Answer (score 0):

Via user YourWelcomeOrMine from the subreddit /r/LanguageTechnology/:

> “I would check out Stanford's CoreNLP. I believe you can customize how
>   a sentence is broken up.”

Answer (score 0):

Via user Breakthrough from Superuser:

> I've found different classifiers using
>   the NPS Chat Corpus training set to be
>   very effective for a similar
>   application.