# Decompose compound sentence to simple sentences

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking for a way to decompose the compound sentence to simple sentences in stanford nlp.
For ex: Input: The manager went home and committed suicide.
Output: The manager went home. He committed suicide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606606/176075

Comment: It will be difficult to automatically infer pronouns as you have done here (i.e., determine that "the manager" can be replaced with "he" and not "she" or "it").

Answer (score 8):

If you are lucky and Stanford parser works correctly on your sentence, you can just decompose the parse tree:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP am)
        (NP (NNP John))))
    (CC and)
    (S
      (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP am)
        (NP (DT an) (NN engineer))))
    (. .)))
```

As you can see, there are 2 S nodes deriving from ROOT-S node. Another way of saying it: Take only the S nodes that don't have S children.

Answer (score 1):

If you would be ok with, "The manager went home, and he committed suicide" (2 independent clauses can be found), maybe check out:

[Clause Extraction using Stanford parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070245/clause-extraction-using-stanford-parser), or

[Independent clause boundary disambiguation, and independent clause segmentation – any tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859892/independent-clause-boundary-disambiguation-and-independent-clause-segmentation)